# Accessing the rows and columns of a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array, iteration

How can I access the rows and columns of a multidimensional array. I want to make a function that reads the rows and columns of an multi dimensional array. For example `row = 0` output would be `{7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5, 1.2, 2.3, 3.5, 4.3, 5.0, 5.5, 6.7}` and column 2 output would be `{6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.8, 5.0}`.

```
int main ()
{
    float Rainfall_amounts[5][12] = {
        {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5, 1.2, 2.3, 3.5, 4.3, 5.0, 5.5, 6.7},
        {8.3, 7.2, 6.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.6, 2.0, 3, 4.38, 4, 5.3, 6.0},
        {7.7, 7.3, 6.2, 0.9, 1.8, 1.3, 2.8, 3.8, 5, 5.5, 5.8, 5.9},
        {7.0, 7.0, 5.8, 0.8, 1.1, 1.8, 3.4, 4.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.8, 6.7},
        {8.2, 6.1, 5.0, 1.2, 0.5, 2.3, 4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.7}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *without a for loop*. Why?? You can by writing the same line of code 12 times. `printf("%d ", Rainfall_amounts[row][0]); printf("%d ", Rainfall_amounts[row][1]); printf("%d ", Rainfall_amounts[row][2]);` etc. But that would be awful code. Or do you mean use a different loop type such as `while`?

Comment: I am new to C so I guess I will just delete the last section without the for loop. Its ok if a loop is used.

Comment: Do you know how to use a loop to iterate a one dimensional array?

Comment: That I dont really know.

Comment: Well then you need to hit a text book or tutorial. That's basic C that is taught in any of those resources. We can spoon feed you an answer but it will be more beneficial for your own long term prospects to learn how to learn effectively.

Comment: Yea I searched it a bit I can do a nested for loop for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is initialised, the `[5]` from `Rainfall_amounts[5][12]` can be omitted; `[]` and the compiler will figure it out. This is good practice if you ever want to add more years without changing the constant. Later, one can use a static `sizeof` to programmatically determine the size in bytes. [cdecl may be helpful](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+float+rainfall_amounts%5B%5D%5B12%5D) to figure out how to use `sizeof` to compute the size of the individual elements.

This code uses the use-case that functions or structures are discouraged; one just wants to print it once. There are many other equally-valid considerations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const float rainfall_amounts[][3] = {
        {7.5, 7.0, 6.3},
        {8.3, 7.2, 6.5}
    };
    const size_t years = sizeof rainfall_amounts / sizeof *rainfall_amounts,
        months = sizeof *rainfall_amounts / sizeof **rainfall_amounts;
    size_t i;

    /* Row 1. */
    for(i = 0; i < months; i++) {
        printf("%s%.1f", i ? ", " : "", rainfall_amounts[1][i]);
    }
    printf(".\n");

    /* Column 1. */
    for(i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        printf("%s%.1f", i ? ", " : "", rainfall_amounts[i][1]);
    }
    printf(".\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The [fprintf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) man page says ".#" is "the number of digits to appear after the radix character." "%s" inserts a ", " before every one except the first.

Answer (score 0):

An example how to code this is shown below.

Please note that there are many different (and better) ways, how to do this. Anyway, it works and it should give you an idea, about what you can do.

COMMENT (personal preference):

- I would consider to store the matrix as a vector in C, like the
  vector includes first column 0, followed by column 1, followed by
  column 2, ... (in the case below with m=5 and n=12, this means vector[60]).
- Then, you access [row, column]-entry, just by vector[row+m*column].
- Next, I would consider just to define the vector (which will hold the matrix) as a pointer, and dynamically allocate its size (using malloc).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_row_or_col(int m, int n, float matrix[m][n], int row, int col, int choose){
   int i;
   if(choose==0) // print row   
   {
      if(!(row<m) || row==-1) return; // return if row exceeds size
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%.1f ",matrix[row][i]);  
   }
   if(choose==1) // print column
   {
      if(!(col<n) || col==-1) return; // return if col exceeds size
      for(i=0;i<m;i++) printf("%.1f ",matrix[i][col]);     
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main ()
{
    float Rainfall_amounts[5][12] = {
        {7.5, 7.0, 6.3, 0.8, 0.5, 1.2, 2.3, 3.5, 4.3, 5.0, 5.5, 6.7},
        {8.3, 7.2, 6.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.6, 2.0, 3, 4.38, 4, 5.3, 6.0},
        {7.7, 7.3, 6.2, 0.9, 1.8, 1.3, 2.8, 3.8, 5, 5.5, 5.8, 5.9},
        {7.0, 7.0, 5.8, 0.8, 1.1, 1.8, 3.4, 4.0, 5.0, 5.2, 5.8, 6.7},
        {8.2, 6.1, 5.0, 1.2, 0.5, 2.3, 4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.7}};
           
    print_row_or_col(5, 12, Rainfall_amounts, 0, -1, 0);
    print_row_or_col(5, 12, Rainfall_amounts, -1, 2, 1);   
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
7.5 7.0 6.3 0.8 0.5 1.2 2.3 3.5 4.3 5.0 5.5 6.7 
6.3 6.5 6.2 5.8 5.0
```